# How to append variable with JsonArrayRequest parameter?

Tags: android, json

I am trying to append UserId with JsonArrayRequest parameter. But when I try to append it it does not entering to the OnResponse function.
Can you help me?

Code

```
 JsonArrayRequest InventoryModelReq = new JsonArrayRequest(url + Userid ,
                                    new Response.Listener<JSONArray>()
                                    {

                                        @Override
                                        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                                            Log.d("RESPONJSN",response.toString());

                                            Log.d("JSONTEST", Userid);
                                            //Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                                            hidePDialog();


                                   }
```

Comment: you want to get userid from json array ?

Comment: got it....just used userid.trim()